# Hide elements inside a DIV, not all the elements in all DIVs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When a user clicks a certain link inside my DIV, I want to hide the specific DIVs inside that DIV where the link was clicked. I use the following code:

```
  $(".entry").on('click', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        // Is the link to show/hide statements clicked?

        if (e.target.className == 'app-link-menu') {

            if ($(this).find('.app-link-menu').text() == 'hide filtered') {
                $(this).find('.nonmatched-sentence').fadeOut(400);
                $(this).find('.app-link-menu').text('show filtered');
            }
            else {
                $(this).find('.nonmatched-sentence').fadeTo(400, '0.4');
                $(this).find('.app-link-menu').text('hide filtered');
            }

        }
```

However, it shows / hides the elements on .nonmatched-sentence class in ALL the .entry DIVs, not only within the one the link was clicked in.

Do you know how to correct that?

Thanks!

UPDATE: HTML

```
        <div class='entry' data-uid='d12ecef0-c243-11e3-bdbd-476fefd65326' data-hashtags='#tarr #bresson'>
            <p class='entry-text'><a href="/concepts/tarr" title="#tarr" class="app-concept-link">#tarr</a> <a href="/concepts/bresson" title="#bresson" class="app-concept-link">#bresson</a> <a title="Search filmDirectors" class="app-context-link" href="/contexts/filmDirectors">@filmDirectors</a></p>
            <p class='entry-date'>13973082279400000</p>
            <p class='entry-menu'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="app-link-menu" href="#">show filtered</a></p>
            <div class='separator'>&nbsp;</div>

        </div>

        <div class='entry' data-uid='cde3e9b0-c243-11e3-bdbd-476fefd65326' data-hashtags='#tarr #sokurov'>
            <p class='entry-text'><a href="/concepts/tarr" title="#tarr" class="app-concept-link">#tarr</a> <a href="/concepts/sokurov" title="#sokurov" class="app-concept-link">#sokurov</a> <a title="Search filmDirectors" class="app-context-link" href="/contexts/filmDirectors">@filmDirectors</a></p>
            <p class='entry-date'>13973082224150000</p>
            <p class='entry-menu'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="app-link-menu" href="#">show filtered</a></p>
            <div class='separator'>&nbsp;</div>

        </div>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML as well?

Comment: Definitely need to see the HTML, but I have a feeling I see the issue. Are you wanting to run the `find()` on the `.entry` button, or `app-link-menu`? You're doing the former with `this` (as that scope belongs to the function, not the conditional statement), but I suspect you want to do the latter. But hard to say without seeing the structure :)

Comment: @NathanHornby actually I do want to run find() on the .entry block from within of which the app-link-menu was clicked.

Comment: try replacing $(this).find ..  with $(e.target).find .. ?

Comment: seems to work okay in this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/us860hof/

Comment: As beast-a-tron said, it seems to be working fine. I have a feeling you wrapped these divs inside another `.entry`.

Comment: That would explain it (or alternatively an `.entry` div that wasn't closed properly) - as it all looks fine to me.